# Unable to browse local drives on Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8.1

When I'm on Remote Desktop my local drives are listed in Windows Explorer under This PC.
But I can't open them (nothing happens when I click on them)!

I can browse the drives if I use \tsclient\C
I can also open files on the drive if I browse to them in the Excel Open File Dialog.

My Remote Desktop session is configured with local ressources.

Can anyone tell me why I can't browse my local drives from Windows Explorer?
And how to fix it?

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to access them.  Please update your question to include this information.

Comment: Well, but nothing happens... updated question...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you open the Remote Desktop interface you have local drives enabled, assuming you mean local to where you're sitting, not where you're accessing. If you switch to the Local Resources tab, click on the More button and then you'll see an option to connect Drives. You can even expand this and select the specific drives.

[image]

Comment: Already done that. The drives are visible in File Explorer but I can't open them.

Comment: What OS are you connecting to? What type of connection are you using? Direct in the same local network or going through any sort of firewalls?